# Summarizing table data with repetitive and nonrepetitive IDs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with building IDs, each ID represents a structure (building, house and etc.). Now if a building has multiple units/condos/apartments then the IDs will be repeated for each of the units.

For each district, 1 and 6 in this case:

1. I am trying to separate repetitive IDs from nonrepetitive IDs.
2. And then count the total number of each repetitive ID and sum their
   dollar value.
3. Lastly create two new columns, `ID_Count` and `Floor`. Whenever an
   ID is repeated more than once, `ID_Count` will be greater than 1
   and Floor will have a value `multistory`

Based on the sample data below how can I do this?

```
    structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 11, 11, 
11, 22, 22, 33, 44, 44, 44, 55, 66), Zoning = c("Residential", 
"Residential", "Residential", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Residential", 
"Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous", "Commercial", 
"Residential", "Residential", "Residential", "Residential", "Commercial", 
"Commerical", "Residential", "Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous", 
"Miscellaneous", "Commercial", "Residential"), District = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
), Value = c(11111, 12111, 13111, 14111, 16111, 17111, 18111, 
19111, 22222, 33333, 11111, 12111, 13111, 14111, 16111, 17111, 
18111, 19111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Desired Output

```
ID  Zoning        District Value  ID_Count  Floor
1   Residential   1        36333  3         multistory
2   Commercial    1        30222  2         multistory
3   Residential   1        17111  1         singlestory
4   Miscellaneous 1        59444  3         multistory
5   Commercial    1        33333  1         singlestory
6   Residential   1        11111  1         singlestory
11  Residential   6        36333  3         multistory
22  Commercial    6        30222  2         multistory
33  Residential   6        17111  1         singlestory
44  Miscellaneous 6        59444  3         multistory
55  Commercial    6        33333  1         singlestory
66  Residential   6        11111  1         singlestory
```

Comment: You can just do it with `data.table`  with `dt <- dt[, .(value = sum(Value), ID_count = .N), list(ID, Zoning, District)][, Floor := fifelse(ID_count > 1, "multistory", "singlestory")]`, where `dt` is a `data.table` object created with `dt <- as.data.table(your_data)`. Notice that there where two typos in your initial data you provided (commerical instead of commercial).

Comment: Fixed, can you please put your code in an answer including the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID,Zoning,District) %>% summarise(n = n(), Value = sum(Value), Floor = ifelse(n>1,"multistory","singlestory"))
# A tibble: 12 × 6
# Groups:   ID, Zoning [12]
#      ID Zoning        District     n Value Floor      
#   <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>      
# 1     1 Residential          1     3 36333 multistory 
# 2     2 Commercial           1     2 30222 multistory 
# 3     3 Residential          1     1 17111 singlestory
# 4     4 Miscellaneous        1     3 59444 multistory 
# 5     5 Commercial           1     1 33333 singlestory
# 6     6 Residential          1     1 11111 singlestory
# 7    11 Residential          6     3 39333 multistory 
# 8    22 Commercial           6     2 33222 multistory 
# 9    33 Residential          6     1 18111 singlestory
#10    44 Miscellaneous        6     3 74666 multistory 
#11    55 Commercial           6     1 44444 singlestory
#12    66 Residential          6     1 55555 singlestory
```

Comment: Tip: in dplyr >= 1.1.0 you could do: `df %>% 
  summarize(ID_Count = n(),
            Floor = ifelse(n() > 1, "multistory", "singlestory"), 
            .by = c(ID, Zoning, District))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same in base R:

```
aggregate(Value ~ ID + Zoning + District, 
          data = df, FUN = function(x) c(ID_Count = length(x), 
                                         Floor = ifelse(length(x) > 1, "multistory", "singlestory")))

   ID        Zoning District ID_Count       Floor
1   1   Residential        1        3  multistory
2   2    Commercial        1        2  multistory
3   3   Residential        1        1 singlestory
4   4 Miscellaneous        1        3  multistory
5   5    Commercial        1        1 singlestory
6   6   Residential        1        1 singlestory
7  11   Residential        6        3  multistory
8  22    Commercial        6        1 singlestory
9  22    Commerical        6        1 singlestory
10 33   Residential        6        1 singlestory
11 44 Miscellaneous        6        3  multistory
12 55    Commercial        6        1 singlestory
13 66   Residential        6        1 singlestory
```